# Matching multiple string characters with regular expressions

Tags: regex

`## (Chat room 1) Received connection request from client 1.

(CR 1) RR 1.

### (Chat room 1) Accepted client 1.

(CR 1) AC 1.

### (Chat room 0) Received connection request from client 2.

(CR 0) RC 2.

### (Chat room 0) Rejected client 2.`[image: Matching string Problem]

The Image above clearly depict my problem. I am trying to match RR,AC and RC . I do not want a broad match but a specific match for either RR or AC or RC
below is my attempted regex that works but its a broad match so long has one of these letters are found

```
(##[^\n]*\n)|(\(CR (\d+))\) [AC\RR\RC\] [0-9]+.
```

Additionally i tried using quotation enclosing each pair letter like this below;

```
(##[^\n]*\n)|(\(CR (\d+))\) ["AC"\"RR"\"RC"\] [0-9]+.
```

It is still a broad match

Comment: It is far from clear. What exact matches do you expect? Why is your pattern written like that? What did you mean to match with it?

Comment: If you want to capture  RR or AC or RC in a group `^##.*\n\(CR \d+\) (RR|AC|RC) \d+\.` https://regex101.com/r/RE1Lra/1

Comment: It would be a kindness to readers if you would replace the picture with text,  enabling them to cut-and-paste if they wish to modify your regex or test a regex against your examples.

Comment: @Thefourthbird it works like a charm thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the leading ## followed by the rest of the line and use  a single capturing group to match one of the 3 alternatives:

```
^##.*\n\(CR \d+\) (R[RC]|AC) \d+\.
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `##.*\n` Match `##`, the rest of the line and a newline
- `\(CR \d+\)`  Match `(CR` and space, 1+ digits and `)`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `R[RC]|AC` Match `RR` or `RC` or `AC`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\d+.` Match a space, 1+ digits and a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vvaxgr/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
\)\s(.{2})\s
```

As pattern is similar have taken the  )   space and group with range of 2 and end with space again .